# show numeric keypad with done button

Tags: html, ionic2, angular2-forms

I'm using following code:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm($event)" style="display: inline-block;">
   <input  type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value=1 class="quantity-value"/>
   <!--<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>-->
 </form>
```

I want to get following output but getting **next** instead of **done**:

[image]

Could someone help me how to show done button instead of next?

I tried by adding following to the **form** but only works for text input type.

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I'm guessing it's saying next because you have more than one input.

Comment: I tried with only one input. code is above.

Comment: Is this android or where exactly does this happen?

Comment: yes on Android. If we uncomment second input and change first input's type number to text then it shows done. I can't figure out why it is not working for number.

Comment: Well since it's native behavior I doubt there's anything you can do about it

Comment: well, Is it preferred to use next button as done so I would need to handle next button as being done pressed?